# Component template variable not updating when service emits a change (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I have a service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthenticationService {
  signInChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  isSignedIn: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.isSignedIn = false;
  }

  signInChange: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  isSignedIn: boolean;

  login() {
    this.auth2.signIn()
      .then(user => {
        this.isSignedIn = true;
        this.signInChange.next(this.isSignedIn)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error signing in")
      })
  }

  logout() {
    this.auth2.signOut()
      .then(user => {
        this.isSignedIn = false;
        this.signInChange.next(this.isSignedIn)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error signing out")
      })
  }
```

and a component:

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  signInSubscription: Subscription;
  isSignedIn: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService) {
    this.isSignedIn = authService.isSignedIn;
    this.signInSubscription = authService.signInChange.subscribe(value => {
      console.log("status changed to: " + value)
      this.isSignedIn = value
    })
  }

  checkValues() {
    console.log("Component says: " + this.isSignedIn);
    console.log("Auth says: " + this.authService.isSignedIn)
  }
```

and here is the HTML:

```
<div id = "login-test">
  <div class="g-signin2"></div>
  <button (click)="signIn()">Sign in</button>
  <button (click)="signOut()">Sign out</button>
  <button (click)="checkValues()">Check values</button>
  <p>{{this.isSignedIn}}</p>
</div>
```

So the observable works as expected (eg. when the sign in status is change the correct status is logged) BUT on the template itself the variable does not update when a change is observed.

Here's what I dont understand:

1. When I click the Check Values button, the output is ALWAYS correct. The isSignedIn property is being set correctly every time there is an update in the service. BUT THE TEMPLATE ITSELF DOESN'T UPDATE.
2. If I set up a button to only toggle the value {{this.isSignedIn}}, the template updates real time. Why will it not update real time if the change is coming from the observable?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the variable `isSignedIn` in `HomeComponent` is assigned once in it's constructor and never re-assigned. And you are on the right path setting up an observable in the service. When you need the up-to-date value in component, use only the observable and do not use the boolean flag from the service directly.

Do the following in the component. Move the assignment inside the subscription and avoid using the boolean flag from the service directly.

```js
import { Component, ngOnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  signInSubscription: Subscription;
  isSignedIn: any;

  constructor(private authService: AuthenticationService, private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.isSignedIn = authService.isSignedIn;
    this.signInSubscription = authService.signInChange.subscribe(value => {
      console.log("status changed to: " + value)
      this.isSignedIn = value;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    })
  }

  checkValues() {
    console.log("Component says: " + this.isSignedIn);
    console.log("Auth says: " + this.authService.isSignedIn)
  }
}
```

**Edit** - include `ChangeDetectorRef`

Comment: I had this already, there was a typo in my question. This still does not work, it will update the value, but the template will not update

Comment: Then I do not understand what is going wrong. It might be easier if you could provide more code.

Comment: Import changedetectorref from angular core then call detectchanges in the obs result

Comment: @JakeChambers: I've updated the answer to include `ChangeDetectorRef`. Please check if it works.

Comment: Yeah this was the answer, I figured it out last night can't get it to work another way.

Comment: @ruth Why do you need to manually `this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` to make it work? Why does it not work without the manual `detectChanges()`?